# Delete a record from Ag-grid using rendered button in Vue file

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm using an ag-grid to populate list records(rows) in a table. I'm trying to delete a record from the grid-table when the user clicks a "Delete" button in one of the cell. I'm able to add the "Delete" button to the grid but how can I capture the index of the clicked "Delete" in the table and remove that row.

table's grid options are defined in file **specials.Vue**

```
*function setGridOptions() {
  this.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [{
      headerName: 'Model',
      field: 'scModel',
      editable: params => this.isCellEditable(params),
      newValueHandler: this.NewValueHandler,
      width: 120,
    }, 
    {
      headerName: 'Delete  ',
      width:50,
      field: 'delete',
      cellRenderer: deleteRecordCellRender,
    },
    ],
    rowData: this.getInitialRowData(),
    headerHeight: 36,
    rowHeight: 28,
    suppressMovableColumns: true,
    suppressMenuMainPanel: true,
    suppressMenuFilterPanel: true,
    suppressMenuColumnPanel: true,
    suppressContextMenu: true,
    singleClickEdit: true,
    rowSelection: 'single',
  };
}*
```

The 'Delete' column rendered from 'deleteRecordCellRender' defined in javascript file ag-gridFunction.js

```
*export function deleteSpecialRecordCellRender() {}
deleteSpecialRecordCellRender.prototype.init = deleteSpecialRecordCellRenderInit;
deleteSpecialRecordCellRender.prototype.getGui = deleteSpecialRecordCellRenderGetGui;
function deleteSpecialRecordCellRenderGetGui() {
  return this.eGui;
}
function deleteSpecialRecordCellRenderInit() {
    console.log('deleteSpecialRecordCellRenderInit this: ', this);

      this.eGui = `<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete-row-button" rel="">Delete</a>`;

  }*
```

delete-row-button function defined in specials.Vue file is

```
$('.delete-row-button').on('click', () => {
      console.log('made it');
      console.log('scope: ', this);
      console.log('clicked row',$scope.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows())
    });
```

But It's not getting the selectedRow due to a scope issue. How do I get the selected row index and delete after ?

Comment: Are you really using Vue? Nothing here looks like Vue.